# Calculate percentiles for groups?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, percentile

How can I calculate percentiles of one field grouped by another field with Elastic Search? I have tried this:

```
GET /dealergeo/sale/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "dom_rank": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "avgdom"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "make",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So basically I want to group all data by *make* and then calculate the percentiles of *avgdom*, but it gives an error:

> {   "error": {
>       "root_cause": [
>         {
>           "type": "aggregation_initialization_exception",
>           "reason": "Aggregator [dom_rank] of type [percentiles] cannot accept sub-aggregations"
>         }
>       ],
>       "type": "aggregation_initialization_exception",
>       "reason": "Aggregator [dom_rank] of type [percentiles] cannot accept sub-aggregations"   },   "status": 500 }

What am I missing here? or is this possible with Elastic Search? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out, I need to wrap the `percentile` aggregation inside the `terms` aggregation instead of the other way around:

```
GET /dealergeo/sale/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "make_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "make",
        "size": 5
    },
    "aggs": {
      "dom_rank": {
        "percentiles": {
          "field": "avgdom"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: yes, aggs" : "percentiles" inside the outer aggs make the trick. Thank you!!